# Saving JSON files and building text corpus for tweets in Python

Tags: python, json, twitter, lda

I'm new to Python from R. I have been creating a topic model for analyzing tweets by tweepy package. I have already extracted the tweets and store them in a variable called `searchresults`;

```
search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q="fisheries",lang="en")
```

As I understood, the `search_results` are in a JSON file. I don't know how to handle/save this file and further process it (it's bit different than R). Could someone tell me how to use this file for further cleaning?

Comment: can you provide some sample data, that you want to operate on?

Comment: You could follow [this tutorial](https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/03/02/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-1/)

Comment: Are you using this library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter?  If thats the case, your assumption, that results are being saved on JSON file is wrong. I guess it search_result is a python dict.  You can inspect its structure by printing this dict out. Then iterate over returned tweets like you would do with any other python dict.